# Regex for express get file path

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, reactjs

Because I am using react router I cannot make specific file path references to every single route with react in Node. In order for their not to be a crash while getting a specific file path, I have to put this code in node.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend-two')));

app.get('*', function(req,res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './frontend-two/index.html'));
});
```

I do, however, want to place a specific file path in order to send json data back to the client. It would interfere with the app.get('*') unless I can figure out a regex for specifically '/users' to be excluded.

Is there anyone who may know a possible regular expression to accomplish this? I have tried ideas through other questions but was unable to figure it out.

Comment: Set up your specific file path before the wildcard, so it will get caught first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

You can add /users path and then * path:

```
app.get('/get', function (req, res) {
    // ...
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    // ...
});
```

The first one matching will be used so the `*` path will not match the `/users` as it's the second one.

Or you can use a regex like this: `/^(?!\/users)$/` that matches everything but not users. There are many ways in which you can compose the regex - search for a negative look-ahead and look-behind assertions.

Comment: I did not think about setting up the specific path before the wildcard path. Thank you very much for your response.